# Reasons for daemon not working

Tags: c, daemon

What are the main reasons Daemons don't work? Like, what am I "allowed" to put inside the infinite loop? Because I have my infinite loop like this:

```
/* The Big Loop */
    while (1) {
       readname(dirSource, dirDest, list1, list2);
       sleep(1); /* wait 30 seconds */
    }
```

It runs once, but that's it.

This is my readname method:

```
void readname(DIR* dirSource, DIR* dirDest, char *list1[], char *list2[]){
sizeSource=0;
sizeDest=0;
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Start saving names of files and directories.\n");
/* save all the names of the files and directories within directory */
while ((ent = readdir (dirSource)) != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(".",ent->d_name)==0 || strcmp("..",ent->d_name)==0){
    }else{

        list1[sizeSource] = strdup(ent->d_name);       
        sizeSource++;
        if(sizeSource>=nE){break;}
    }
}
closedir(dirSource);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Finished saving names from source directory.\n");
while((ent1 = readdir (dirDest)) != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(".",ent1->d_name)==0 || strcmp("..",ent1->d_name)==0){
    }else{
        list2[sizeDest] = strdup(ent1->d_name);
        sizeDest++;
        if(sizeDest>=nE){break;}
    }
}
closedir(dirDest);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Finished saving names from destination directory.\n");
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Finished saving all names.\n");
mkdir("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Test", 0700);
```

}

If the method only has the `mkdir` line, it works fine, it's stays in the infinite loop. But when I add the rest of the code, it only executes once. What's wrong?

Comment: You have verified that it completes all of full version of `readname`, but just the one time?

Comment: See also [Daemon not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275350/daemon-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to open DirSource and DirDest

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown where you freed all the memory you allocated with `strdup()`.  Running out of memory because you leak it is a prime reason for daemons to fail after some time.  However, it would take fairly large directories to cause you to fail on the first cycle.

Inside a daemon, you can do almost anything you can do inside a non-daemon, but there are usually things you won't want to do.  You won't be interacting with a user.  It is likely that standard input will be `/dev/null`; your code will need to read from other places.  You need to consider whether your daemon will be run with standard output and standard error connected to a log file of some sort.

Daemons fail for similar reasons that other programs fail.  They don't check error conditions.  They try to do things that are not allowed.  They are more prone to memory exhaustion than interactive programs because they run for long times — but that is not solely the prerogative of daemons.